# <Suspense /> and React.createElement

Tags: typescript, react-test-renderer, react-suspense, react-testing

In .tsx, this works as expected:

```
const LazyComponent = lazy(() => import("path-to-my-lazy-component"));
const SuspenseComponentTSX = (
  <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
    <LazyComponent />
  </React.Suspense>
)
render(SuspenseComponentTSX);
```

But the supposed equivalent in .ts does not work:

```
const LazyComponent = lazy(() => import("path-to-my-lazy-component"));
const SuspenseComponentTS = React.createElement("Suspense", { 
   fallback: React.createElement("div", null, "Loading")
 },
 React.createElement(LazyComponent)
);
render(SuspenseComponentTS); // fails
```

The error message when trying to render SuspenseComponentTS is the following:

```
    A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.

    Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.
```

Printed to console, they appear to be equivalent:

Output of `expect(SuspenseComponentTSX).toEqual("")`:

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: ""
    Received: <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}><UNDEFINED /></React.Suspense>
```

Output of `expect(SuspenseComponentTS).toEqual("")`:

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: ""
    Received: <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}><UNDEFINED /></Suspense>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
React.createElement("Suspense", {
```

strings only work for the basic dom elements, such as "div", "span". To render a React.Suspense, you need:

```
React.createElement(React.Suspense, {
```